# Win & Commandline: remember current working directory?

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm developing Rails under Win7, the default path when opening CMD is `D:\Sites`, and then I go into my current working repo, `D:\Sites\my_project`, using `cd my_project`.

The problem is that, I need to `cd my_project` **everytime** I want to work on this project.

I think a simple approach, is to make the `CMD` remeber the current working directory(or last working directory), so **next time** I open this `CMD`, it will automatically into `D:\Sites\my_project`.

Notice:

You might suggest just change my `default dir` into `D:\Sites\my_project`, but this would hurt if I want to work on another project, like  `D:\Sites\my_project_2`, which would result constantly changing the `default dir`, and `remembering last dir` will not have this problem.

Comment: How are you starting `cmd.exe` ?  (One possible solution would be to create a shortcut to `cmd.exe` with the desired current directory, and use that.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston, yes, and I set that to `D:\Sites\`. Changing it to `D:\Sites\my_project` would have some future problem, t I've mentioned it in the `Notice` above.

Comment: What's stopping you from having two or more shortcuts?  Anyway, I suppose what you're asking for is possible in principle; you can have the shortcut run a batch file that sets the current directory, and you could track the changes by, say, injecting a DLL into cmd.exe that checks the current directory periodically, or by calling a batch file (instead of using the "exit" command or the close button) to exit the command window when you're done.